# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' in Python - Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

```bash
$ python --version
Python 3.9.13
```

I have tried:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

also tried

```
pip install opencv-python
```

and both getting the same error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling in case it was corrupt and not having any luck.
Below are the errors.

```
Matt Dolly@Matt-PC MINGW64 ~ $ pip uninstall opencv-python
Found existing installation: opencv-python 4.6.0.66
Uninstalling opencv-python-4.6.0.66:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\sherri\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages\cv2\*
    c:\users\sherri\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages\opencv_python-4.6.0.66.dist-info\*

Proceed (Y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled opencv-python-4.6.0.66

Matt Dolly@Matt MINGW64 ~ $ pip3 install opencv-python
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv_python-4.6.0.66-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl (35.6 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in c:\users\sherri\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.23.0)
Installing collected packages: opencv-python
Successfully installed opencv-python-4.6.0.66
```

I just started the project so not much code yet just trying to get the library cv2 library imported

```py
import cv2


cv2.waitKey(0)

print("Code Completed")
```

Comment: Run this python code and show us the output `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: what are you running code in? jupyter notebook through browser, vscode IDE, spyder IDE, terminal? If an IDE, you may need to chose your python interpreter

Comment: check if they are the same: `python3 -m pip -V` and `pip3 -v`

Comment: @smcrowley VSCode python terminal

Comment: @MattDolly if you type ctrl+shift+p while in the IDE, you can then type "select: python interpreter". Make sure the python interpreter selected matches the path when you type ```which python``` in terminal. you may need to type ```which python3``` if python2 is installed

Comment: @JohnGordon $ C:/Users/Sherri/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/Sherri/Desktop/Face_Detector/Face_Detector.py
['c:\\Users\\Sherri\\Desktop\\Face_Detector', 'C:\\Users\\Sherri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Sherri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs', 
'C:\\Users\\Sherri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Sherri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310', 'C:\\Users\\Sherri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages']

Comment: Looks like you have a version mismatch.  `pip3` is installing packages in `c:\users\sherri\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9...`, but `python` is looking in `C:\Users\Sherri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310`.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too, try running

```
pip install opencv-python
```

in a virtual environment. To create one run

```
python3 -m venv tutorial-env
```

and then activate the virtual environment.

```
tutorial-env\Scripts\activate.bat
```

for windows.

Once you have done this run the pip install and then it should work.

Comment: if you're using a virtual environment, can I suggest conda or miniconda? nicer management and dev experience IMO

Comment: @smcrowley I am downloading that now.  The answer above I just tried and still not working.

Comment: @greens trial I just tried this and still not working unfortunately.

Comment: @MattDolly can you find opencv in the list when you run ```pip list``` ?

Comment: @greenstrial 
$ pip list
Package                Version
---------------------- --------
numpy                  1.23.0
opencv-contrib-python  4.6.0.66
opencv-python          4.6.0.66
opencv-python-headless 4.6.0.66
pip                    22.1.2
setuptools             63.1.0
wheel                  0.37.1

Comment: @MattDolly are you using vscode?

Comment: @greenstrial Yes I am using vscode.

Comment: @MattDolly okay you may need to change your interpreter, something like that, you can search that up on google. I had the same issue with vscode, but it worked fine in pycharm so I had to change my python interpreter in vscode, don't remember the exact steps, and then it worked.

Comment: @MattDolly so search changing python interpreter for a virtual environment in vs code.

Comment: @greenstrial So I downloaded Anaconda followed the steps on https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/setup-anaconda-python-to-work-with-visual-studio-code-on-windows/ then did ctrl + shift + p typed in Python and found the environment think I am good to go thanks everyone so much